# bundle get Serializable / Activity crashes

Tags: android, bundle, extras

I have a problem when I try to start my SecondActivity in my app..
I retrieve a list of objects from my FirstActivity but the secondactivity keeps crashing..

FirstActivity:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ScanFiltersActivity.this, ScanRegionsActivity.class);
              Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
              bundle.putSerializable("regionlist", beaconRegions);
              mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
              startActivity(mainIntent);
```

SecondActivity:

```
 Bundle secondBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    regionsList = (ArrayList<IBeaconRegion>) secondBundle.getSerializable("regionlist");
```

Any solutions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the crash report in question .

Comment: implement a serializable interface in your `IBeaconRegion` class

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kontakt.sample/com.kontakt.sample.samples.ScanRegionsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Regions collection is null. This is what i get as error but my list size is 1. Also i can't modify the class to extend serializable because it seems to be locked from the kontakt.io sdk which i have implemented..

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to implement Serializable in your POJO class like this

```
public class IBeaconRegion implements Serializable{
     // your variables , getter setters
}
```

Hope this helps.